# Replacing a Freeradius library

Tags: freeradius, libraries

I have a freeradius 2.0.4 server i want to update.it has been running without interruption for 2 years.
My update consists only in updating the *chap* module without creating a new one.
To avoid discontinuity of service and be sure that all configs remain the same, i am trying to find a smooth way to do that on a testing machine.
I thought it would be possible to simply **replace the rlm_chap-2.0.4.so library with my modified version of it**. but this produces a segfault (most probably caused by a library conflict).

Other information:
 - Freeradius starts and segfault is produced when the chap module is call at the first request.
 - My library works fine when it is used along with the compiled version from sources of freeradius
 - I am using 2 versions of Freeradius: 2.0.4 installed through an apt-get install and the compiled version from apt-get sources
 - The library conflict is caused by the modified library and by nothing else. If i restore the original version of rlm_chap-2.0.4.so (and do nothing else) it works fine again.
 - I am still a noob in compilation/library manipulations/freeradius, so i'm probably doing a lot of things wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "library conflict".

But anyway, you shouldn't do this. If you're modifying rlm_chap it must be built against the same version of the source as libfreeradius and radiusd.

If you're attempting to use a packaged version of rlm_chap from a more recent release of FreeRADIUS (say 2.2.0) it likely will not work because the internal APIs of FreeRADIUS may of changed.

With FreeRADIUS 3.0.0 this is explicitly forbidden. The server will refuse to start if it loads a module linked against a different version of the library.

It will also refuse to start if it was built with a different version of OpenSSL to the one it's linking to at runtime.

If you're set on updating rlm_chap, you will need to download the official release of 2.0.4, swap out the rlm_chap code in src/modules/rlm_chap, attempt to build the module, fix any build errors, and then use that version in place of the current .so.

Comment: I solved my problem myself but forgot to post it here, I was actually misunderstanding the difference between compiling and building from the source code. A "./configure make make install" uses different compilation options and settings than a "fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc" as described in [freeradius wiki](http://wiki.freeradius.org/building/Build). When building from sources, the libraries were perfectly interchangeable.
Thanks anyways

Comment: I will still mark your answer as the right one for you last paragraph.